# How get from $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}$ this $n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, summation, exponential-function

in that [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990668/does-sum-n-0-infty-1n-e-1-frac1nn-converge-absolutely-condi/990679#990679)  Chen Jiang(second answer) show how to prove $\frac{1}{4n}< e -\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}  \right)^n$

I dont understand how, he do that
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}
>n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$

More precisely, from $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}$ this $n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$

if it takes the first degree ($i=0$) of sum, he take $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^0\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$
or i don't notice something?

I understand that  $\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right) -\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}$
This formula $a^n - b^n =(a-b)...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2i}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^i}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}=$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{4n^2+4n}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}>\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}=n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}\ge\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^i\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1-i}=n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$$